# Querying Parse for Users notContainedIn constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am running and application that when you like or dislike another user the result is stored in either an array of "accepted" (liked) or array of "rejected" disliked. The array contains the users objectId that you liked/disliked.

When I am querying for results I am using the whereKey:notContainedIn method:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];  
[query whereKey:@"objectId" notContainedIn:[PFUser currentUser][@"accepted"]];

[query whereKey:@"objectId" notContainedIn:[PFUser currentUser][@"rejected"]];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                self.displayedUserId = object.objectId;
                NSLog(@"userId: %@", self.displayedUserId);

                PFFile *imageFile = object[@"image"];
                [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        self.userImage.image = image;
                    }else {
                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                    }
                }];
            }
        }else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];
```

An error of:

> [__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

I am not to sure how to debug or next steps.

Comment: Are either "accepted" or "rejected" set to (undefined) in the dashboard?

Comment: ^ as @JakeT. said, objective-c will throw an error if you try to reference an array with nonzero length but contains nil as the first element

Comment: IOS + parse hates nil. If you need to use it for some reason, use [NSNumber numberWithNil:nil] or whatever it is. Also, if the issue is just that the array is completely undefined, you can add a beforeSave() trigger to your user object in cloud code, check request.user.isNew(), and if it is, set the "accepted" and "rejected" fields to an empty array.